# Change file name and move files based on file path in Windows 7

Tags: windows, file, command-line, scripting

I have a bunch of image files distributed in folders and sub folders. What I would like to do is move them all to one one folder and rename them them based on their previous path.

To illustrate, the file src/a/b/file1.png

should become src/a_b_file1.png

There is probably a smart way to do this in Linux, but I am currently on a Windows 7 machine.

Any tips would be nice, gui or commandline tools or some script, doesn't matter. Thanx.

Comment: This is a common question, use Google or search the forum. What have you tried so far?

Comment: The only one I have actually tried out is this [this](http://nicj.net/windows-command-line-regular-expression-renaming-tool-renameregex/) tool.

However I have searched Google and the only things I could find only seemed to support renaming given some regular expression (like the link above), but they did not seem to support using the path of the files as part of the target file name. But maybe there is something I am not understanding...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using [this](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php) program. Easy to install and easier to use that it appears at first glance.

Answer (score 3):

Try this: and then examine renfile.bat in notepad to see if it is right for you.
Add more filetypes if you need them.

```
@echo off
echo.@echo off> renfile.bat
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *.jpg *.png *.gif /b /s /a-d ') do call :next "%%a"
echo renfile.bat created
pause
goto :eof
:next
set "var=%~1"
call set "var=%%var:%cd%=%%"
set "var=%var:\=_%"
>>renfile.bat echo ren "%~1" "%var:~1%"
```

and another batch file to move all the files once they are renamed:

```
@echo off
md "c:\target folder\"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *.jpg *.png *.gif /b /s /a-d ') do (
move "%%a" "c:\target folder\"
)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use [advanced renamer](http://www.advancedrenamer.com/user_guide/tags_default), the tool offers a great number of renaming tags, eg.

```
[DirName:X] Inserts the last directory name. eg. "c:\windows\notepad.exe" will give "windows" as result.

If X is a numeric value that value will be used to select a folder name in the sequence from the right part of the path.

[Dirname:3] for "c:\programs\games\new\mine sweeper\highscore\file.txt" will yield "new"
[Dirname:4] for "c:\programs\games\new\mine sweeper\highscore\file.txt" will yield "games"
```